# PixiJS issue with container

Tags: pixi.js

Weird issue with container, i load images as

```
        let tileSet = PIXI.BaseTexture.from('Dungeon_Tileset.png');
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                this.textures[i + j * 10] = new PIXI.Texture(tileSet, new PIXI.Rectangle(i * 16, j * 16, 16, 16));
            }
        }

and then

return new PIXI.Sprite(this.textures[ind]);
```

in case I add sprites directly to the stage like

```
app.stage.addChild(sprites[j * 100 + i]);
```

everything is fine
in case I add sprites to a container that added to the stage - sprites "shift" for 1px

```
let container = new PIXI.Container();
app.stage.addChild(container);
container.addChild(sprites[j * 100 + i]);
```

[image]

can't understand what is wrong

[image]

textures
[image]

Comment: Did you changed scale or resolution / device pixel ratio somewhere? This may have something to do with it. If not then consider adding issue in: https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues

Comment: no, nothing, it starts like
```
    const app = new PIXI.Application({
        autoResize: true,
        resolution: devicePixelRatio,
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
    });
```